# Add many sort position to document

Tags: mongodb

I have Document with field: _id, title, one, two, positionOne, positionTwo
For example:

```
_id  | title | one | two | positionOne | positionTwo
1    | aaa   | 12,2| 10  |             |
2    | bbb   | 3,2 | 12,2|             |
3    | ccc   | 12,6| 2   |             |
4    | ddd   | 3   | 4   |             | 
5    | eee   | 5,5 | 5   |             |
```

And I would like receive:

```
_id  | title | one | two | positionOne | positionTwo
1    | aaa   | 12,2| 10  |      2      | 3
2    | bbb   | 3   | 12,2|      4      | 2
3    | ccc   | 12,6| 2   |      1      | 5
4    | ddd   | 3   | 4   |      4      | 4
5    | eee   | 5,5 | 15  |      3      | 1
```

I would like add positions from max to min. 
Is this possible only with Mongo queries to db?

Comment: please clarify your question. it's not clear what do you want to add (whether data in the positionOne or positionTwo fields or something else).

Comment: @lesingerouge: yes, I want add data in the positionOne and positionTwo. There are sort position from max to min

Comment: Please elaborate your question with example. Vague question will not get any help.